# 'Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap' - SetIcon on Google Map Marker throwing an error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting the following error when trying to set an icon on a Google Maps Map Marker:

> [ERR] 26/06/2018 10:02:25 a.m. : Failed to decode image. The provided
>   image must be a Bitmap. [ERR] 26/06/2018 10:02:25 a.m. :   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <0711a0626e0e4d58a44e8ca32787a4a9>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in
>   <5680b8d3acca4700bde9a113c467e3e5>:0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00017] in
>   <5680b8d3acca4700bde9a113c467e3e5>:0    at
>   Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker.SetIcon
>   (Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptor icon) [0x0004b] in
>   <51f505f20f3f4c27854ba8f47994abdb>:0    at
>   AMCS.Mobile.Mapping.Android.MarkerManager.UpdateMarker
>   (AMCS.Mobile.Entity.Mapping.IMarker markerInfo) [0x00083] in
>   :0    at
>   AMCS.Mobile.Mapping.Android.MapHelper.UpdateMarker
>   (AMCS.Mobile.Entity.Mapping.IMarker markerInfo) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   AMCS.Mobile.AMCSMobile.Client.Android.CollectionRouteView.b__462_0
>   () [0x00000] in <1d292c66dbaa42139a432bad3cbbbc7b>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   <5680b8d3acca4700bde9a113c467e3e5>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00008] in <5680b8d3acca4700bde9a113c467e3e5>:0    at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:6aee8cf7-156f-44a9-94d5-15cb0790d815 (intptr,intptr)
>   --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace --- com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to
>   decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.    at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.n.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685024@12.6.85
>   (040406-197041431):12)    at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685024@12.6.85
>   (040406-197041431):7)     at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cy.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685024@12.6.85
>   (040406-197041431):186)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.q.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685024@12.6.85
>   (040406-197041431):87)    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
>     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.l$a$a.n(Unknown Source)
>     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setIcon(Unknown Source)
>     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)  at
>   mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)

I can see that it's failing in the UpdateMarker method which looks like the following:

```
    public void UpdateMarker(IMarker markerInfo)
    {
      // _markerLookup is a dictionary defined earlier as:
      // private Dictionary<IMarker,Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker> _markerLookup = new Dictionary<IMarker, Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker>();
      // It is populated elsewhere
      // Check if the dictionary contains a key for the given value
      if (_markerLookup.ContainsKey(markerInfo))
      {
        Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker marker = _markerLookup[markerInfo];
        marker.Position = new LatLng(markerInfo.MapCoordinate.Lat, markerInfo.MapCoordinate.Lng);
        marker.Draggable = markerInfo.MarkerOptions.IsDraggable;

        // Create BitmapDescriptor from Resource - Blue_Vehicle definitely exists and is a .png image
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDesc = 
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.Blue_Vehicle);

        if (bitmapDesc != null)
        {
          marker.SetIcon(bitmapDesc);
        }  
      }
    }
```

The marker.SetIcon method is looking for a BitMapDescriptor which as described above is created from an image resource.

I don't understand why it's throwing an exception.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Is your `Blue_Vehicle` drawable actually a bitmap-based resource (png/jpg...) or a vector?

Comment: It's definitely a png